Android emulator not launching
Recently I got error when trying to launch Android emulator in Visual Studio.

Device error: WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\ldanelia.android\avd..\avd\pixel_5_-api_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5-_api_34'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=467c81c4-2cb3-4ffc-9ff6-545cbba6933f'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
added library vulkan-1.dll
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
[15468:7264:20241210,123005.059:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ldanelia\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\6a4bf382-a625-4c76-9afc-61f5afc1ea39: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[15468:7264:20241210,123005.060:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\ldanelia\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\6a4bf382-a625-4c76-9afc-61f5afc1ea39: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[15468:7264:20241210,123005.060:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)

I've tried : clear cache, delete Temp folder , reinstalling Android sdk/emulator/each tool, delete .android folder, clear solution. But still.

Check whether the corresponding files in the directory are visible, and update the emulator version to ensure compatibility.
